Does python not automatically convert integer types when doing math?
I had an issue with a collision function returning very large values for distances
I would think python would not overflow a 16 bit integer when doing this math, since it's dynamically typed, but apparently it does.
If I were to do these operations directly on an array, I understand why it would overflow, but here it is copying the value to another variable, x1, x2, ... , y3, and then doing math on those to create distance variables.
I would assume python would use 64 bit integers on those. But it doesn't. They are still 16 bit.
I suspect, under the cover, its not really creating any new variables, just assigning them by reference.
Is this always the case, or does it only happen when using numpy arrays? This is one of the really frustrating things about python coming from being a c++ programmer.
def create_square(self, img):
    color = self.random_color()
    x = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[1] - square_size, dtype=np.uint16)
    y = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[0] - square_size, dtype=np.uint16)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + square_size, y + square_size), color, -1)
    return (x, y, square_size, color)

def collide(self, square1, square2, square3):
    x1, y1, size1, _ = square1
    x2, y2, size2, _ = square2
    x3, y3, size3, _ = square3

    # Calculate distances between squares
    distance1 = (x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2
    distance2 = (x1 - x3) ** 2 + (y1 - y3) ** 2
    distance3 = (x2 - x3) ** 2 + (y2 - y3) ** 2
    print("distance1",distance1)
    print("distance2",distance2)
    print("distance3",distance3)
    # Check if all distances are below the threshold
    if distance1 < (size1 + size2)**2 and distance2 < (size1 + size3)**2 and distance3 < (size2 + size3)**2:
        return True
    return False

def reset(self):
    # Reset squares
    self.squares = []
    for _ in range(num_squares):
        self.squares.append(self.create_square(np.zeros((600, 800, 3), dtype=np.uint16)))

Here is the output of distances
distance1 -18581859
distance2 -52348750
distance3 -46958403


do you have to use np.randint ? why not just rand.randint

Inputs, expected outputs and minimal code?

why not either use rand.randint or convert to int instead of keeping crappy 16 bit type? and yes [mcve] is a few steps away.

You specified x and y to be dtype=np.uint16.  Why?  Check the dtype (or type) of distance1.   While python int can be arbitrarily large, numpy ints are limited to np.int64.

if x1 and x2 are of type np.int16 like x and y, then (x1 - x2) is of type np.int16 so (x1 - x2)**2. The later can easily overflow (with an absolute values >=256). Thus, you should certainly convert it to np.int32 or possibly bigger. Numpy applies (mostly) the C type promotion rules. Operations involving the same type never cause the output type to be different, and the result can overflow (or be possibly undefined). The output types are not automatically adapted for sake of performance (smaller types tends to be faster due to SIMD units in CPUs)

On the other hand, you can use Python integers which are unbounded but also much slower (because they are actually unbounded).

Clearly something is overflowing, because it's impossible for the sum of two squares to be a negative number otherwise.  On the other hand those results are bigger than what will fit in a int16.

Neither Numpy nor Python does dynamic type conversion based on its values. This is typically done in operations between different types. And there is no reason why simply copying to another variable (which, as you suspected, actually creates a view) would change its type.

@JérômeRichard I believe small integers in Python are reasonably well optimized, you only pay a penalty when you're working with really large ones.

@MarkRansom A quick test on my machine (i5-9600KF CPU) with CPython 3.8.1 shows that adding integer variables (8 additions per statements to mitigate other overheads) with the value 1 results in 29 ns per addition (105 cycles), while the same thing with 128 bit numbers results in 43 ns (155 cycles), and 51 (184 cycles) for 512 bit ones. The overhead of the benchmarking system is just few ns. Thus, variable-sized integers are not so expensive but small ones are expensive! My CPU can do 4 x 64-bit scalar int operations/cycle (not to mention SIMD units). This is >400 times faster than CPython.

@MarkRansom That being said, AFAIK newer version of CPython should be faster for that. Still I do not expect this to be more than twice faster even on the latest release. I guess they can do better but I expect the overheads to come from things like reference counting, dynamic typing, the interpreter itself and internal pointer indirections due to dynamic objects. It is not easy to reduce these overheads in a very dynamic language like Python.

Regarding your assumption:

I would think python would not overflow a 16 bit integer when doing this math, since it's dynamically typed, but apparently it does.

No, Numpy scalars are not dynamically typed.
Summarizing some of the existing comments and quoting the docs:

The numpy integer types mirror the behavior of C integers, and can therefore be subject to Overflow Errors.

>>> np.seterr(all='ignore');
>>> a = np.int16(20000)
>>> b = np.int16(30000)
>>> a - b
-10000
>>> a + b
-15536

